# Is there a way to notify GitHub users of an update in one of my repos?

Tags: github

I have a Github repo which hasn't been updated for a long while (up until today).

I would like to notify users who cloned it in the past that the repo has been updated and that they better pull the changes.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GitHub webhooks](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/about-webhooks)  for this. You'll have to read the docs and add your own consumption logic for it.

If you rather not build your own consumption pipeline, consider using [LightFlare](https://lightflare.bytebeacon.com) (I'm the creator) that has out of the box support of consuming Webhooks events from many services (github included) and notifies you at your choice(s) of destinations (slack / email etc ...).